# domain/IN: has no NS records

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, reverse-dns, dns-zone

I have set up a home web server using Ubuntu 12.10 and I can safely say that it works with regards to router forwarding and ports being found. I know this, because switched my hosting provider's VPS SOA record to use my ISP IP with an 'A' value and had my website running from home. This verified that my server was configured correctly so I started what I believe to be the final step in making my old desktop into a full DNS server.

I found [this](http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/) tutorial that got me started My LAN network consists of the following:

- My router with a gateway of `10.0.0.zzz`
- My server with an IP of `10.0.0.xxx`
- A laptop with an IP of `10.0.0.yyy`

### Step 1:

I installed bind via `sudo apt-get install bind9`

### Step2:

I configured `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` with:

```
zone "sognwebdesign.no" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/sognwebdesign.no.db";
};

zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

### Step3:

Updated `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` with two ISP DNS addresses

### Step 4:

Updated `/etc/resolv.conf`with:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.xxx
search lan
search sognwebdesign.no
```

### Step5:

created a ``/etc/bind/zones directory

### Step6:

Created `/etc/bind/zones/sognwebdesign.no.db`with:

```
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.sognwebdesign.no. admin.sognwebdesign.no. (
2007062001
28800
3600
604800
38400
);
sognwebdesign.no.      IN  NS          ns1.sognwebdesign.no.
sognwebdesign.no.  IN      NS          ns2.sognwebdesign.no.
sognwebdesign.no.  IN      NS          ns3.sognwebdesign.no.
NS1                IN      A           10.0.0.1
NS2                IN      A           10.0.0.2
NS3                IN      A           10.0.0.3
www                IN      A           10.0.0.4
yuccalaptop        IN      A           10.0.0.19
gw                 IN      A           10.0.0.138
                       TXT        "Network Gateway"
```

### Step 7:

created`/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa`with:

```
$TTL 3D
@  IN SOA ns.sognwebdesign.no. admin.sognwebdesign.no. (
            2007062001
            28800
            604800
            604800
            86400
);
zzz       IN      PTR     gw.sognwebdesign.no.
1         IN      PTR     ns1.sognwebdesign.no.
2         IN      PTR     ns2.sognwebdesign.no.
3         IN      PTR     ns3.sognwebdesign.no.
yyy       IN      PTR     yuccalaptop.sognwebdesign.no.
```

I then restart bind and `dig-x sognwebdesign.no` and it works
Lastly I perform `named-checkzone`on each of my zone files, but me reverse zone fail fails with:

```
sognwedesign.no/IN: has no NS records
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here or assist me in getting this configured correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you're using `named-checkzone` incorrectly:

1. Use it ***BEFORE*** you reload the zones or restart your name server.
   The whole point of this utility is to catch errors that would cause your zones to fail to load. It can't help you avoid mistakes if you've already restarted the server before you let it check for errors.
   (BIND will happily run the same checks though, and fail for the same reasons - look at your log files.)
2. It's impossible for a check on `0.0.10.in-addr.arpa` to generate an error message referring to `sognwedesign.no`, unless you're specifying the wrong zone name to named-checkzone.
   Specify the correct zone name in accordance with [the manual for `named-checkzone`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone).

---

Second of all, `named-checkzone` is right about the problem it's reporting -- there are no NS records in your reverse zone.
Correct the issue (add NS records) to make the message go away.

This isn't black magic -- If you use the tools correctly they tell you exactly what's wrong, all you have to do is fix it.